# How I get react component in html file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, yarnpkg

I have made web-page by pure js,css and django.
Feeling so ineffective then I try to use React js.
However, when I make simple react component all, there is one problem that I don't know how to use this component on current html file.

Would you tell me how I get 'App component' from main.html?

**main.html**

```
     ...

     <main class="mainPart" style="height: 100%; position: relative; top: 170px; ">
        <div class = "bodyPart" >
           <div id="bodyPartWrapper">

          <script type="text/babel">

           var App = ?????? 'how to get App Component?'

           ReactDOM.render(
              <App />,
               document.getElementById('bodyPartWrapper')
            );

          </script>

           </div>
        </div>
     </main>

     ...
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">title goes here</h1>
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </div>
        );
      }
    }
export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use react without any build pipeline. It can be implemented just as any normal JS library.

In your case the simplest solution will be doing something like this:

Add these scripts right before the closing `</body>` tag:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
```

Inside your HTML file give an id to an element (you did that already) and add React code.

```
<div id="bodyPartWrapper"></div>

<script type="text/babel">
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">title goes here</h1>
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </div>
        );
      }
    }

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('bodyPartWrapper'));

</script>
```

And that's it. React is just JS :)

React Docs are super good, check them out: https://reactjs.org/

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I want to bring other react js file(like App.js) not create react component on html file. Could I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You have the script tag inside the div you are rendering react, try to put the script outside the div tag.

Answer (score 0):

you have to import the App file and the render it in the div you want

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('bodyPartWrapper'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

you can also just add in your App.js file this :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

//(...)
//this at the end of the file
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('bodyPartWrapper'));
```

If you just want to import the App component you can do

```
import App from './location/to/App'
```

Comment: In a different file, did you use create-react-app?

Comment: Really thanks for reply, Could I get App component (not create) on html file? I'd like to import react component in html and render it also in html.

Comment: you can import it as i showed you in the code above but i think if you add this line and remove the export in the App.js it should work just as fineReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('bodyPartWrapper'));

Comment: But if you really want to you import it like so :

import App from './location/to/App'


and then use it like this: <App/>

Comment: you also have to impor the other stuff:
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

Comment: if this fixed your problem please accept the answer

Comment: you have to remove the tag script from inside the div aswell if you are doing it like that

Comment: You need to install react dependency like react, react-dom etc.

Comment: True, i was assuming he already did that since he was calling the functions